# jQuery Flot chart order by date

Tags: jquery, date, plot, flot

I'm struggled with jQuery Flot chart, the chart is being populated fine with this data:

`{"facebook_users":[["25",0],["26",0],["27",0],["28",0],["29",0],["30",0],["31",0],["01",0],["02",0],["03",0]],"email_users":[["25",0],["26",0],["27",0],["28",1],["29",1],["30",3],["31",1],["01",0],["02",0],["03",0]],"max":10}`

Producing this chart:

[image]

As you may noticed, this is a chart that shows the users registered by email/address in a day by day basis. The problem is that it appears to reorder the JSON data ascending, starting from 1 to XX. As this data is 7-days long, can be month-cross, provoking the error.

I've readed carefully the [project documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md), but can't find a solution. The chart should show the data as the JSON, without reordering.

Comment: Can you not simply add the month to the date indicator? (06/01, 06/02 etc.)

Comment: @Archer I already tried it and, if you add the month (by putting 06-01 or 06/01) then the flot plugin doesn't plot anything.

Answer (score 2):

Flot isn't re-ordering the data; it's just that the values are [x, y] pairs, and an X value of 1 is plotted at the same position on the x-axis regardless of where it appears in the sequence.

There are several ways to solve this:

- Use the time plugin, provide the values as timestamps instead of days, then use a formatter of '%d' to extract just the day portion.
- Provide your own tick generator function to produce them in the order you want, i.e. 30, 31, 1, ...
- Use the categories plugin to interpret the values as strings rather than numbers.

Comment: Thank you @DNS, I will try the solutions you mention and tell you about.

Comment: I also found this very useful [tutorial](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-time-series-chart.html) regarding time series